# create index on data base could not determine size of temporary file "0"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am facing the issues on create index on a table that has more than 1m rows.

```
could not determine size of temporary file "0"
```

Comment: What is your exact postgres version (`select version();`) and which operating system are you using?

Comment: Possibly this bug: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15512-b3f236e85cecabd1%40postgresql.org

Comment: i am using 11 version of postgres